# Java: Why would anyone ever write super() when this is the default?

Tags: java, constructor, super

Why would anyone ever write

```
super(); //(parameterless)
```

inside a subclass constructor, since if this is absent, the default, parameterless superclass constructor is called anyway?

Comment: There is no practical use in calling the `super()` constructor. When I use it, i do it to remind myself that the super-constructor is called so i won't forget that (for debugging etc...)

Comment: @ParkerHalo that _is_ a practical use :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually generate constructors using IDE (i.e. Eclipse), and it actually places that call, so that could be one of the cases

Comment: Yes it is typically a code styling from eclipse (from some eclipses).

Answer (score 2):

The parameterless super() constructor is just one part of the list of super constructors with various parameters you could call

```
super(int, String)
super(int)
super()            // for completeness
```

Even though some teams may require the call due to styling reasons, the call of the no-args super() does not achieve anything and thus is simple code-bloat. (Some people like it like that.)

Answer (score 0):

To make explicit the (otherwise implicit) control flow.

Such code serves as a reminder that the superclass default constructor will in fact be called at the beginning of the derived class' constructor. Those reading the code will have a visual marker that reminds them to also check the superclass constructor when they want to know what  happens when an instance is constructed.